# codeschool jQuery Return Flight 5.10 on click handler failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into an odd issue with codeschools jquery course where my on click handler is not working. The question we are trying to solve in 5.10 is:

> For starters create an event handler using on, that targets the
>   .see-photos link within each .tour. When this is clicked, run a
>   function that will add a class of is-showing-photofy to the tour.
>   You'll probably want to save a reference to this outside of your event
>   handler, and use that in the click event handler.

My current code attempt is:

```
$.fn.photofy = function() {
  this.each(function() {
        var tour = $(this)
    tour.on('click.see-photos', 'button', function() {
        $(this).addClass('is-showing-photofy');
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tour').photofy();
});
```

and the error message I am getting is:

```
Your `on` `click` handler should watch for clicks on the `.see-photos` element within the current tour
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the following:

- prevent default
- var tour = $(This)

Final Code:

```
$.fn.photofy = function() {
  this.each(function() {
        var tour = $(this);
    tour.on('click.photofy', '.see-photos', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        tour.addClass('is-showing-photofy');
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tour').photofy();
});
```